# How can I 'namespace' my prototypes

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I intend to namespace my library of useful methods but my library also includes a number of prototypes. For example,

```
// Utility Functions    - Trim() removes trailing, leading, and extra spaces between words
String.prototype.Trim = function () { var s = this.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,""); return s.replace(/\s+/g," "); };
// Escapes characters for use with a regular expression
String.prototype.EscapeR = function () { return this.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"); };
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
    if ( !this.mthName ) this.mthName = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    return this.mthName[this.getMonth()];
};
```

How can I (or should I) include them within my namespace?

(Please note that I am not using JQuery.) Thanks for any hints in advance. Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just use a custom namespace prefix. However, you can do some sneaky things using Mozilla's non-standard `__noSuchMethod__`: Using [monkey.js](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/monkey.js), you could do

```
var names = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
    'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ];

MONKEY.patch(Date).getMonthName = function() {
    return names[this.getMonth()];
};

var date = MONKEY(new Date);
alert(date.getMonthName());
```

A standard-compliant version can be done once [ECMAScript-Harmony proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies) have landed...

Comment: Huh that's a clever way of not adding global functionality (can interfere with existing stuff). I should take a look at this *monkey*.

Comment: the current implementation of `MONKEY()` still has the same issues (ie naming conflicts) if it's used by independant cripts; however, once you have a proxy, it shouldn't be too hard to add some namespacing capabilities; I'll take a look I have some more time...

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate them in a commonly-named sub object, like:

```
String.prototype.stuff = {
  Trim: function() { ... }
}
Date.prototype.stuff = {
  getMonthName: function() { ... }
}
```

Of course, this only keep your methods namespaced relative to their container object but I assume that's what you're shooting for.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, although perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm a bit new to namespacing. I like the MONKEY solution but assume that this is yet another library? Can't I have my own 'patch' method? "won't work as this will point to the wrong object" - not sure which answer this is referring to? Andy.

Comment: I've started the process of namespacing my little library but I refer to 'this' within a function and I believe it still refers to my class rather than the function object it is within. How can I tell it that 'this' within 'this' means 'this current object'. Make any sense?